# Clase o método para poner color a todos los textbox de mi proyecto al tener foco "Enter en c#"

Tags: c#, windows-forms, interfaz-gráfica

Necesito una clase o método c# que aplique cambios de color a los `TextBox` cuando tengan foco de forma global sin necesidad de hacerlo desde cada    `TextBox`

.

Ok, tengo lo siguiente.

Clase

```
namespace despachos.clases
{
    class propiedadesTxb
    {
        /*Inicia propiedad para elementos tipo TextBox*/
        public void colorTxb(TextBox var)
        {
            var.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        }
        public void noColorTxb(TextBox var)
        {
            var.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
        /*Fin propiedad para elementos tipo TextBox*/       
}
```

Llamado desde los textbox

```
 private void txbvalor_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {               
    PropiedadesTxb.colorTxb(txbvalor);            
 }
```

Comment: ¿que has intentado hasta ahora? si solo pides código la pregunta es candidata a ser cerrada, te sugiero que agregues parte de tu código o código de ejemplo en caso de que no puedas agregar el tuyo por seguridad, así la comunidad será mas propensa a ayudarte.

Answer (score 4):

Podrias crear una clase que se adjunte al evento y defina funcionalidad a los textbox

Podrias crear un extension method

[Métodos de extensión (Guía de programación de C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-AR/library/bb383977.aspx)

```
public static class TextBoxExtension
{
    public static void AttachEnter(this Form frm)
    {
        var textBoxList = frm.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();

        foreach(var item in textBoxList)
        {
            item.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
            item.LostFocus += textBox_Enter;
        }
    }

    public void textBox_Enter(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
    {
        TextBox ctrl = (TextBox)sender;

        ctrl.BackColor = Color.White;
    }

}
```

se usaria

```
public class Form1 : Form 
{
    public void Form1_Load(...)
    {
        this.AttachEnter();
    }

    //resto codigo
}
```

De esta forma se adjuntan a todos los textbox la misma funcionalidad que define el color de fondo y controla el evento `enter`.

En este caso el `this` es el propio Form

Answer (score -1):

Crea tu propio TextBox heredando de él, así irá nativo en el control.

```
public class MiTextBox : System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
{


    private void MiTextBox_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }


    private void MiTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.White;
    }


    public MiTextBox()
    {
        LostFocus += MiTextBox_LostFocus;
        GotFocus += MiTextBox_GotFocus;
    }
}
```